# LiveCode: Capture still image from camera on a desktop computer?

Tags: image, camera, desktop, capture, livecode

How do I capture a still image from camera on a desktop computer using LiveCode?

I'm using this code to capture image on mobile devices:

```
mobilePickPhoto "front camera" ,100 , 100
```

Answer (score 1):

First use the video grabber external to set up the camera.

```
revIinitializeVideoGrabber the short name of this stack,"QT","20,20,120,86"
```

Now you can grab a frame:

```
revVideoFrameImage 66,100,myPictureData
```

and set the imageData of an image control:

```
set the imageData of img 1 to myPîctureData
```

and now export it as PNG for instance

```
export img 1 to myPictureData as PNG
```

You can write myPictureData to a file.

The revVideoGrabber external may not work with the latest versions of LiveCode.